# Which version of Node.js should I choose

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I am planned to build a web application based on Node.js. As a common sense I installed the latest version of Node.js (v0.10.0). I was also suggested to use express.js to avoid use low level APIs.

When I was trying to install express.js package, I found it could not be installed becase some dependices are missing. So, I tried to install all missing dependices one by one. All packages are OK for installation except formidable.js which requires node.js version to be less than 0.9.0("node": "<0.9.0")}. I was frustrated, because for my new development I would like to use the newest stalbe version of Node.js rather than choose a very early version (0.9.0).

So, if I still want use express.js, should I really roll back my node.js to an earlier version (<0.9.0)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node `0.10.0` is relatively new and many frameworks and libraries do not support this version yet.

Node `0.9.x` was an unstable release as every odd-numbered version (every even numbered version is considered stable, e.g., `0.6.x`, `0.8.x`, `0.10.x`, ...).

For starting you might use the latest `0.8.x` version and upgrade to `0.10.x` later as libraries evolve.

The node versioning schema may be found here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-versioning-scheme

**Hint:** There is the tool [Nave](https://github.com/isaacs/nave) which allows you to use several node installations at once.

#### Edit 2013-12-04

Meanwhile Node `0.10.x` is very stable and should be chosen.

Comment: OK, I did not notice that. Is this a rule of Node.js that odd-numbered version is relative unstable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Node Version Manage (nvm)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to play with different versions of node. That said I would stick with 0.8 for now if you are just starting out

Comment: This is actually wrong, NVM is used to install packages. I think you meant `nave`.

Comment: You are probably thinking of [NPM](https://npmjs.org/) which is the Node Package Manager. NVM and NPM are different

Answer (score 1):

instead of going with new version I suggest you to check the version your framework and libraries supported.

in Node.js maybe old libraries are not updated with latest version of nodejs that you want to use.